# Should I test an exact result of algorithm or just test some elements of the result?

Tags: java, algorithm, unit-testing, graph

I've written a BFS algorithm and I'd like to test the algorithm.

I've written tests in 2 approaches because I realized that for example the way of storing adjacent vertices may change and the order will be different so the result will be different but not necessarily incorrect.

Test of full path:

```
@Test
void traverse_UndirectedGraph_CommonTraverse() {
    BreadthFirstSearchTest<String> breadthFirstSearchTest= new BreadthFirstSearchTest<>(undirectedGraph);
    assertIterableEquals(Lists.newArrayList("A", "B", "E"), breathFirstSearch.traverse("A", "E"));
}
```

Test if the path contains an initial vertex and a terminal vertex:

```
@Test
void traverse_UndirectedGraph_CommonTraverse() {
    BreadthFirstSearchTest<String> breadthFirstSearchTest= new BreadthFirstSearchTest<>(undirectedGraph);
    List<String> path = breathFirstSearch.traverse("A", "E");
    assertEquals("A", path.get(0));
    assertEquals("E", path.get(path.size() - 1));
}
```

Is any of these two approaches correct?
If no how would you test that algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is any of these two approaches correct?

Probably. But that is *hard* to say without exactly understanding your full requirements and your context, like the classes/data structures your search is relying on.

> If no how would you test that algorithms?

I would follow TDD.

Meaning: you start with writing tests **first**.

To be precise:

- you write one simple test
- you ensure the test fails
- you then write *just enough* "production" code so that your test passes
- you maybe refactor your code base (to improve its quality)
- go back to step 1

In other words: you develop your algorithm while gradually walking from small, simple tests, to more advanced scenarios.

Beyond that, you can also look at this from a true "tester" perspective. Meaning: you *totally* ignore the implementation. Instead, you look at the problem, and at the *contract* that the production code should follow. And then you try to find examples for all important cases, and most importantly: edge cases. You write those down, and then run them against your implementation.

(most like: your two test cases are way too simple, and you would need many more)

Comment: I see, but should I test even in these simple tests an exact result or just some of the result elements?

Comment: @Syzak That very much depends. Ideally, your tests only fail when the result is in-correct. Example: if *order* doesn't matter ... why use lists in the first place. You could then be returning sets, and then there is no worrying about order of elements.

Answer (score 1):

For cases that have at most one traversal, the simplest verification is by exact match.

For cases that have multiple valid traversals, verification could be either by matching against the enumerated traversals, or by verifying the breadth-first property of the traversal.

For cases which have many valid traversals, verifying the breadth-first property seems to be necessary.

Working from the problem as stated:

Key features are that the graph is un-directed, and the search is breadth first.

No other characteristics of the graph are specified.  The graph is assumed to possibly have cycles, and is assumed to not necessarily be connected.  For simplicity, at most one edge is present between nodes, and no edge is present from a node to itself.

As basics, a traversal which is obtained by a breadth first search must be a subgraph of the searched graph.  That is, each edge of the traversal must be an edge of the searched graph.  Also, the initial node of the traversal must be the beginning node of the search and the final node of the traversal must be the target node.

In each case, the search must not get into an infinite loop, and must obtain a breadth first result.  Or, must indicate that a traversal is not possible.

Testing should demonstrate a variety of cases, for example, traversal of a list, a tree, a loop, a bipartite graph, or of a complete graph.

One test methodology builds a collection of test graphs (enumerating at least the variety of cases described above), and builds a collection of test cases for each of the graphs.  The test cases would supply the initial and final nodes of the case, and would supply the collection of valid traversals.

Supplying the collection of valid results is easy if there is zero, one, or perhaps a handful of valid paths.  For particular graphs, there can be many traversals, and as an alternative there might need to be a way to verify the "breadth-first-ness" of a traversal, as opposed to enumerating the possible traversals.

For example:

```
A <-> B1, B2 <-> C1, C2 <-> D1, D2 <-> E
```

Here A <-> B1, B2 means that there is an edge between both A and B1 and between A a B2.  Similarly, B1, B2 <-> C1, C2 represents the complete bipartite graph of B1 and B2 with C1 and C2.

There are eight valid breadth-first traversals from A to E.

There are traversals which are not valid breadth first traversals, for example:

```
( A, B1, C1, B2, C2, D1, E )
```

Also for example, for the simple graph:

```
A <-> B, C
B <-> C
```

A breadth first traversal from A to C must yield ( A, C ) and not ( A, B, C ).  A depth first traversal may obtain either ( A, C ) or ( A, B, C ) depending on whether the traversal steps from A to B first, or steps from A to C first.

One characterization is, if minimum distances are assigned to nodes, starting with the initial node of the traversal, then a breadth-first traversal must never step from a node to node that is closer to the initial node.

Labeling the first example with distances gives:

```
A(0) <-> B1(1), B2(1) <-> C1(2), C2(2) <-> D1(3), D2(3) <-> E(4)
```

Similarly labeling the second candidate traversal gives:

```
( A(0), B1(1), C1(2), B2(1), C2(2), D1(3), E(4) )
```

This is not a valid breadth-first traversal because the edge C1 -> B2 decreases the distance from the initial node.